# Fast algorithm computing multiplications of 2$^{n}$ number of decreasing natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Let A=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)  ... 4 multiplications.

But, we can reduce it to using 2 multiplications.

1. n(n-3)= n$^{2}$-3n = X
2. (n-1)(n-2)= n$^{2}$-3n+2 = X+2

Therefore: A=X*(X+2) ... 2 multiplications.

Because ((n+a)$^{2}$+b) is a polynomial of order 2.
(((n+a)$^{2}$+b)$^{2}$+c) is of order 4 using 2 multiplications.
((((n+a)$^{2}$+b)$^{2}$+c)$^{2}$+d) is of order 8 using 3 multiplications
...

In general, I guess  multiplication of 2$^{n}$ number of decreasing(or increasing) natural numbers can be done by just using n multiplications.
But how, if it is possible?

**Conclusion:**
miracle173 suggested that computing those unknown variables a,b,c,d,... in
the guess, general form of repeating squaring would be as difficult as factoring a number.
While Simon gave an algorithm that shrinks the problem to
twice faster than directly multiplying from the
problem definition.

**Update1:**
I just figured out the solution: n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7)=
((n$^{2}$-7n+7)$^{2}$-21)$^{2}$+448n-784-64n$^{2}$
I.e. 2$^{3}$ number of decreasing natural numbers can be computed using just 3 multiplications, though not exactly the form in the beginning guess.
So it is reasonable to move on the conjecture to the next level: Could computing the product of 16 decreasing/increasing
natual numbers be done by using 4 multiplications?

Comment: if you are able to multiply $m (=2^n)$ numbers in $\log(m) (=n)$ steps, you would be able to calculate $(m-1)! \bmod(m)$ in polynomial time. This number is $-1$ if m is a prime and $\ne-1$ if m is composite ([Wilsons Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)). So you would be able to decide if $m$ is a prime in polynomial time. From this I would conclude there is no simple algorithm to calculate $n!$ in polynomial time because the [first polynomial primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) was discovered 20 years ago.

Comment: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63491?#comment-474166 mentions a $O(\sqrt n\log n)$ algorithm using FFT.

Comment: I think it is as hard as factoring. But I think factoring is not NP complete.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding an idea mentioned here: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63491?#comment-474113
For the following considerations we assume that $m! \bmod n$ can be calculated in polynomial time. This is the case if $m!$ can be calculated in polynomial number $O(\log m)$  of multiplications and additions. Then you would be able to calculate $([\sqrt n  ]+1)! \bmod n$ in polynomial time. If $n$ is composite its smallest prime factor $p$ is smaller or equal $\sqrt n$ and so  $p | ([\sqrt n  ]+1)!$. Therefore  $p | ([\sqrt n  ]+1)! \bmod n$ and so $$p|\gcd(([\sqrt n  ]+1)! \bmod n,n).$$ Either you have found a proper divisor of $n$ or there is at least a divisor less or equal then $\sqrt[3]n$ and you can repeat this procedures. So if you continue in this way you would have a polynomial factorization algorithm. At the moment no polynomial factorization algorithm is known.

Comment: The questions are 1.Computing factorial and modulo are different things
2.P=NP is still unknown

Comment: @wij: ad (1) if I understand you right then computing the factorial of an integer m  and computing factorial of  an integer  m modulo n  are different thinks. This is true and this is why I wrote that I assume that m! can be calculated by O(log n) multiplications (and additions). If these are the only operations involved the algorithm can be simply extended to modular arithmetic by replacing these operation by modular multiplication and modular addition. If  there is comparisons of the size of subproducts  or divisions of such products, this cannot be easily extended to modular arithmetic.

Comment: @wij: ad (2) It is unknown if P=NP holds but that is not relevant here. I wanted to show that the OP could not expect that there is an algorithm known  that needs O(log n) multiplications to calculate n! because then a polynomial algorithm to factor integers would be known. 
I used you input to rephrase my preconditions and conclusions to make them more clear to the readers. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I made a conclusion, please see if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you found a nice trick to evaluate $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ with only 2 multiplications instead of the naive $3$. But Im afraid you are wrong about the generalization to larger products. Here is something that actually works:

Let $$f_k(n) = (n+2k-1)(n+2k-3)(n+2k-5)...(n-2k+5)(n-2k+3)(n-2k+1)$$
This has $2k$ terms in total, requiring $2k-1$ multiplications when done naively. But reordering the product gives
\begin{align}
f_k(n) &= (n+1)(n-1)(n+3)(n-3)(n+5)(n-5)...(n+2k-1)(n-2k+1) \\\\
&= (n^2-1)(n^2-3^2)(n^2-5^2)...(n^2-(2k-1)^2).
\end{align}
This way only takes $k$ multiplications (one to compute the square $n^2$ and $k-1$ to multiply all the terms). Your formula is a rescaled and shifted special case of this:
\begin{align}
n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) &= f_2(2n-3)/16
\end{align}
similarly
\begin{align}
n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5) &= f_3(2n-5)/2^6 \\\\
n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)(n-6)(n-7) &= f_4(2n-7)/2^8
\end{align}
and so on.

Overall this trick saves around a factor of two. Not more.

Comment: I made a conclusion, please see if it is appropriate.